# How to make a link only column in HTML table

Tags: html-table, htmltable-control

I have one format for html page. But it does not apply link but apply as a text in the html table.

There was no link everything was a text.

The format is like as below;

```
<title>Report</title>
<style>
table
{
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td
{
font-size:1em;
border:1px solid #98bf21;
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
th
{
font-size:1.1em;
text-align:center;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-right:7px;
padding-left:7px;
background-color:#A7C942;
color:#ffffff;
}
name tr
{
color: #060606;
background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I want to make a link only column. So I think i have to change that td area. I tried refer to the other pages. It did not work...

Comment: I suggest you loot at some tutorials and try some simple examples first.  Because this makes no sense at all.

Comment: https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/7163/creating-linked-html-with-powershell/

Comment: that table is from the page above. in the page, the writer wrote that it works. but it does not apply a link as a link but a text.